# Send back rows and readstream in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, amazon-s3, multer-s3

Hey I would like to send back an image downloaded from s3 and data from MySQL database but i'm not sure if its even possible and if it is, how to do it.

Any help is welcome thanks!

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId)
        connection.query(`SELECT username, picture, DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, "%d %M %Y") as creation_date from users where idusers = ${id}`, (err, rows) => {
            connection.release() // return the connection to pool

            if (!err) {
                
                const readStream = getFileStream(rows[0].picture);
                readStream.pipe(res);

                res.send(rows[0])
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: Think about it from the client's point of view. You issue a GET `/api/users/1` - what are you going to get? JSON? A picture? A response needs to be of some mimetype, like application/json or image/jpeg. Even if you manage to cram the image into JSON somehow, putting it in an <img> will be awkward.

Comment: hmm so I guess that means its not possible to to it this way.. do you have any suggestions on how to do it?